# How can I import all files in a folder?

Tags: dart

Say I got a bunch of dart scripts in a folder,

Is there anything I can do like `import 'foo/*.dart'`?

P.S. What if I got an array of filenames and wanna import those files?

Comment: To your update: doesn't change anything. If this really is a problem you can create a transformer that generates the imports but this doesn't solve warnings about missing imports during development.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to import each library individually.

What you can do is to create a library that imports all other libraries and reexports them.
you can then import this one library and get all libraries imported at once.

```dart
library all_in_one;

export library1.dart;
export library2.dart;
export library3.dart;
```

Comment: Can you just write `export` in this file if you don't need to actually use any of these libraries in `all_in_one` ?

Comment: thanks! But the point is, I still have to manually write a line for each file. Is there any way I can do this dynamically?

Comment: I understand that in your question but Dart doesn't provide such a feature. You can write a script that does it. Can you provide more information about your use case? Where do the files come from?

Comment: Say I'm writing a tiny framework for my web app, I may got several controllers and templates in individual scripts. It's a little bit annoying that I have to import each of the script right?

Comment: Maybe a bit but on the other side you have full control and adding an import line isn't that much work. Often you use it like in your other question that you import some things into one library and export a few more abstract things, this way you generate some hierarchy like a tree. If you need everything on the top level there might be something wrong with your design. Controllers and templates sounds like Angular - are you using Angular.dart?

Comment: Nah, angular's huge and i'm working on a tiny one for my own app. Currently I'm trying that transformer thing to achieve my aim. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 12):

You could also use the "part of" library composition:

Create 1 .dart file that is your lib eg.: lib.dart and add at the start of this file.:

```
library lib
```

For every file in your folder add a:

```
part "somefile.dart"
part "otherfile.dart"
```

In all files that are part of this library add at the start:

```
part of lib
```

In other files and libs you can then import all those file just via:

```
import "lib.dart"
```

This will import all the parts of your library (folder). Keep in mind that the "lib.dart" file is now responsible for all the imports of your lib files. So to import something to "somefile.dart" you add the import to "lib.dart". All imports are then available in all the lib files.

Comment: This way is the better because show only one suggestion in the autocomplete of the VSCode.

Comment: The part approach is better than exporting due to potential type conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

This would be highly unsecure, this is why it is not allowed by design. An attacker would be able to run any malicious code just adding a file with the right name to your folder.

Comment: If an attacker has write access to a directory containing code, wildcard import is the least of your problems. Scopes are never intended to provide security.

Comment: @JoeLapp well actually it's a known attack vector, for example by abusing outdated upload scripts. I worked at a place that got hacked exactly in that way. Of course the upload script was the real culprit but the attack vector is real.